# Fetch expression from string [java]

Tags: java

I am trying to fetch a part of string that may be an expression. I didn't find any way to do this. Problem is that I have a string that have may have one or more expressions and I have to fetch them.

For example, string is: -

```
    IF [100]>[102] THEN [100]-[102] ELSE [102]-[100]
```

Now, here `[100]` is representing a value, will be retrieved from database using `100` as primary key and same as for `[102]`, so how to fetch the following

```
    [100]-[102]
```

and

```
    [102]-[100]
```

expressions from given string.

Thank you!

Comment: I do not quite understand what you want to achieve? Your String is a -. Is that the mathematical meaning or just a textual representation?
If I understand you correctly you want to subtract two values from each other which you get from your database. Is that correct?

Comment: Please provide a real example (runtime values) instead of the above representation.

Comment: easiest way is to create regex for simpler expressions. For anything more complex you will have to use a parser generator. You can use GATE, ANTLR, JFlex etc. This may be a good start http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators

Comment: It is just like to fetch `(21)+(22)` or we can say `21+22` from string `evaluate the following: (21)+(22)`. If this becomes possible everything will be alright.